# Directing animation to correct place

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my word game there is a grid with 3 letter words.

The aim of the game is to spell the words by clicking on the corresponding letters on the side.

When an area in the grid is highlighted it indicates to the user the word to spell. The user clicks the letters on the side of the grid and they should move to the highlighted area.

I have recently changed "drop-box" to a div in the following piece of code and now the animation takes the letter to the top corner of the grid before taking it to the correct position.

```
    var row = '<tr>';
    var spaceAvailInRow = numLetters;
    while (spaceAvailInRow) {
        var word = getWordToFitIn(spaceAvailInRow, unusedShuffledWords);
        guesses[word] = [];
        spaceAvailInRow -= word.length;

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            row += '<td data-letter="' + word[k] + '" data-word="' + word + '"><div class="drop-box"></div></td>';
        }
    }
    row += '</tr>';

    tbl.append(row);
}

$(".container").append(tbl);
```

Can someone tell me why the animation has broke now I have changed this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7A5/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `position()` gets an element's position relative to its (offset) parent - in your case, each `drop-box` div is positioned at 0,0 releative to its containing `td`. What you need is the containing `td`'s `position()`, not the `drop-box`'s.

I've changed things around a little, and the fiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mHDkV/1/

I've changed the `targetPos` variable to refer to the position of the parent `td`, and applied the `occupied` class to that `td` as well. Take a look though the code in the jsFiddle - it should hopefully make sense.

Comment: But now the wordglow styles do not take effect when a word is right or wrong @MassivePenguin

Comment: I've re-forked your example, leaving the `occupied` class alone, and just changing the `targetPos` reference. The colour changing issue stems from the fact you're looking at the `drop-box` for the `data-letter` variable, which it doesn't have. You need to look for `target.parents('td').data("letter")` instead. See: http://jsfiddle.net/mHDkV/3/

Comment: Ok is that why it treats everything as a correct answer yet the colour is red? @MassivePenguin

Comment: That problem is because you're looking inside the `drop-box` div for the `data-letter`, when it's actually one level deeper (a `div` inside the `drop-box` div). Change `$(this).data("letter") == $(this).find("div").data("letter")` to `$(this).data("letter") == $(this).find(".drop-box div").data("letter")` and it'll work - see http://jsfiddle.net/mHDkV/4/

Comment: It is still treating incorrect answers as correct ones though. Is it maybe something to do with the variable "spellWord" @MassivePenguin

Comment: Whoops - I got my code wrong! This one works: http://jsfiddle.net/mHDkV/5/ (`$(this)` refers to the `drop-box` div, which in itself has no `data-letter` attribute. You need to compare the `data-letter` of the parent `td` with the `data-letter` of the child `div` to get the correct result). Change `$(this).data("letter") == $(this).find(".drop-box div").data("letter")` to `$(this).parents('td').data("letter") == $(this).find("div").data("letter")`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18801/discussion-between-massivepenguin-and-milo-j)